# Video recording using camera 2 for Portrait and Landscape in Android

Tags: android, video, android-camera2

I am implementing video recording using Camera 2 API. Video is getting recorded and uploaded, playing also.

But it works fine in Portrait mode. When I am recording in landscape mode, it is not showing in Landscape. Orientation is a bit odd and is playing reversed.

My code snippet is here:

```
public class Camera2VideoFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final int SENSOR_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_DEGREES = 270;
    private static final int SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT_DEGREES = 90;
    private boolean orientation = true;
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    private static final String TAG = "Testing";
    boolean flag = false;
    private static final String VIDEO_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Powerconsent";


    private static final SparseIntArray INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    private static final SparseIntArray DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();


    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }


    /**
     * An {@link AutoFitTextureView} for camera preview.
     */
    private AutoFitTextureView mTextureView;
    /**
     * Button to record video
     */
    private ImageView mButtonVideo;

    /**
     * Button to record video
     */
    private ImageView mSaveVideo;

    private File mOutputFile;

    /**
     * A refernce to the opened {@link android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice}.
     */
    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
    /**
     * A reference to the current {@link android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession} for preview.
     */
    private CameraCaptureSession mPreviewSession;
    /**
     * {@link TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener} handles several lifecycle events on a
     * {@link TextureView}.
     */
    private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener
            = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture,
                                              int width, int height) {
            openCamera(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture,
                                                int width, int height) {
            Log.d("Testing", "onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged");
            configureTransform(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
            Log.d("Testing", "onSurfaceTextureDestroyed");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
//            Log.d("Testing", "onSurfaceTextureUpdated");
        }
    };
    /**
     * The {@link android.util.Size} of camera preview.
     */
    private Size mPreviewSize;

    String destVideoPath = null;

    /**
     * The {@link android.util.Size} of video recording.
     */
    private Size mVideoSize;

    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = null;
    /**
     * Camera preview.
     */
    private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewBuilder;
    /**
     * MediaRecorder
     */
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;

    private File mCurrentFile;

    Chronometer mChronometer;
    /**
     * Whether the app is recording video now
     */
    private boolean mIsRecordingVideo;

    private Integer mSensorOrientation;
    /**
     * An additional thread for running tasks that shouldn't block the UI.
     */
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;
    /**
     * A {@link Handler} for running tasks in the background.
     */
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    /**
     * A {@link Semaphore} to prevent the app from exiting before closing the camera.
     */
    private Semaphore mCameraOpenCloseLock = new Semaphore(1);
    /**
     * {@link CameraDevice.StateCallback} is called when {@link CameraDevice} changes its status.
     */
    private CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
            startPreview();
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            if (null != mTextureView) {
                configureTransform(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            cameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice cameraDevice, int error) {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            cameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
            Activity activity = getActivity();
            if (null != activity) {
                activity.finish();
            }
        }
    };

    public static Camera2VideoFragment newInstance() {
        Camera2VideoFragment fragment = new Camera2VideoFragment();
//        fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
        return fragment;
    }

    /**
     * In this sample, we choose a video size with 3x4 aspect ratio. Also, we don't use sizes larger
     * than 1080p, since MediaRecorder cannot handle such a high-resolution video.
     *
     * @param choices The list of available sizes
     * @return The video size
     */
    private static Size chooseVideoSize(Size[] choices) {
        for (Size size : choices) {
            if (size.getWidth() == size.getHeight() * 4 / 3 && size.getWidth() <= 1080) {
                return size;
            }
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable video size");
        return choices[choices.length - 1];
    }

    private void screenAlive() {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, "Testing:");
        wl.acquire(120*60*1000L);
    }

    /**
     * Given {@code choices} of {@code Size}s supported by a camera, chooses the smallest one whose
     * width and height are at least as large as the respective requested values, and whose aspect
     * ratio matches with the specified value.
     *
     * @param choices     The list of sizes that the camera supports for the intended output class
     * @param width       The minimum desired width
     * @param height      The minimum desired height
     * @param aspectRatio The aspect ratio
     * @return The optimal {@code Size}, or an arbitrary one if none were big enough
     */
    private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int width, int height, Size aspectRatio) {
        // Collect the supported resolutions that are at least as big as the preview Surface
        List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<Size>();
        int w = aspectRatio.getWidth();
        int h = aspectRatio.getHeight();
        for (Size option : choices) {
            if (option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * h / w &&
                    option.getWidth() >= width && option.getHeight() >= height) {
                bigEnough.add(option);
            }
        }
        // Pick the smallest of those, assuming we found any
        if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
            return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable preview size");
            return choices[0];
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private int currentOrientation = -1;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("Testing","onCreateView !!!");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera2_video, container, false);
        RelativeLayout frameLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.toplayout);

        mChronometer = new Chronometer(getActivity());
//        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) frameLayout.getLayoutParams();//new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(50, 50, 0, 0);
        mChronometer.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/psans.ttf");
        mChronometer.setTypeface(font, Typeface.NORMAL);
        mChronometer.setTextSize(20);
        mChronometer.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
//        mChronometer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        mChronometer.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        frameLayout.addView(mChronometer);
        screenAlive();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mTextureView = (AutoFitTextureView) view.findViewById(R.id.texture);
        mButtonVideo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.mRecordVideo);
        mButtonVideo.setOnClickListener(this);
        mSaveVideo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.mSaveVideo);
        mSaveVideo.setOnClickListener(this);
//        view.findViewById(R.id.info).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("Testing","onResume !!!");

        startBackgroundThread();
        if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
            openCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
        } else {
            mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.mRecordVideo: {
                if (mIsRecordingVideo) {
                    stopRecordingVideo();
                } else {
                    mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    mChronometer.start();
                    startRecordingVideo();
                }
                break;
            }
            case R.id.mSaveVideo:

                File destinationPath = new File(String.valueOf(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)));
                File file = new File(destinationPath.getAbsolutePath());
                AppLogger.d( "Video destination Path::  "+file.toString()+ "  "+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
                mOutputFile = getCurrentFile();
                Log.d("Testing", "Output file path:: "+mOutputFile.getAbsolutePath());
//                notificationBuilder.setProgress(PROGRESS_MAX, PROGRESS_CURRENT, false);
//                notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notificationBuilder.build());
                Uri videoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
                        APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", mOutputFile);
                Intent service = new Intent(getActivity(), VideoCompressionService.class);
                // Add extras to the bundle
                service.putExtra("videouri", videoURI);
//                service.putExtra("destVideoPath", destVideoPath);
                service.putExtra("destVideoPath", mOutputFile.getPath());
                // Start the service
                getActivity().startService(service);
                getActivity().finish();
                break;
        }
    }

    protected File getCurrentFile() {
        return mCurrentFile;
    }

    /**
     * Starts a background thread and its {@link Handler}.
     */
    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("CameraBackground");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }

    /**
     * Stops the background thread and its {@link Handler}.
     */
    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Tries to open a {@link CameraDevice}. The result is listened by `mStateCallback`.
     */
    private void openCamera(int width, int height) {
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null == activity || activity.isFinishing()) {
            return;
        }
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            if (!mCameraOpenCloseLock.tryAcquire(2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");
            }
            String cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            // Choose the sizes for camera preview and video recording
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics
                    .get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            mSensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
            Log.d("Testing", "Sensor Orientation: "+mSensorOrientation);
            mVideoSize = chooseVideoSize(map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class));
            mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                    width, height, mVideoSize);
            int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            Log.d("Testing", "normal Orientation: "+orientation);
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            } else {
                mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
            }
            configureTransform(width, height);
            mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            manager.openCamera(cameraId, mStateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Cannot access the camera.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            activity.finish();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // Currently an NPE is thrown when the Camera2API is used but not supported on the
            // device this code runs.
            new ErrorDialog().show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera opening.");
        }
    }
    private void closeCamera() {
        try {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.acquire();
            if (null != mCameraDevice) {
                mCameraDevice.close();
                mCameraDevice = null;
            }
            if (null != mMediaRecorder) {
                mMediaRecorder.release();
                mMediaRecorder = null;
            }
        }
//        catch (InterruptedException e) {
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "exception:: "+e.getMessage());
//            throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera closing.");
        } finally {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        }
    }
    /**
     * Start the camera preview.
     */
    private void startPreview() {
        if (null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewSize) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            setUpMediaRecorder();
            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
            List<Surface> surfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>();
            Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
            surfaces.add(previewSurface);
            mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);
            Surface recorderSurface = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
            surfaces.add(recorderSurface);
            mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(recorderSurface);
            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    mPreviewSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                    updatePreview();
                }
                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Activity activity = getActivity();
                    if (null != activity) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    /**
     * Update the camera preview. {@link #startPreview()} needs to be called in advance.
     */
    private void updatePreview() {
        if (null == mCameraDevice) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            setUpCaptureRequestBuilder(mPreviewBuilder);
            HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("CameraPreview");
            thread.start();
            mPreviewSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void setUpCaptureRequestBuilder(CaptureRequest.Builder builder) {
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
    }
    /**
     * Configures the necessary {@link android.graphics.Matrix} transformation to `mTextureView`.
     * This method should not to be called until the camera preview size is determined in
     * openCamera, or until the size of `mTextureView` is fixed.
     *
     * @param viewWidth  The width of `mTextureView`
     * @param viewHeight The height of `mTextureView`
     */
    private void configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null == mTextureView || null == mPreviewSize || null == activity) {
            return;
        }
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
        RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
        float centerY = viewRect.centerY();
        if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
            bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
            matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
            float scale = Math.max(
                    (float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight(),
                    (float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth());
            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
            matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
        }
        mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
    }
    private void setUpMediaRecorder() throws IOException {
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null == activity) {
            return;
        }
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mCurrentFile = getVideoFile(activity);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getVideoFile(activity).getAbsolutePath());
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(2000000);
//        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        Log.d("Testing", "Captured rate::: 15");
//        mMediaRecorder.setCaptureRate(15.03);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(1280, 720);
//        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        Log.d("Testing", "rotation value:: "+rotation);
        int orientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation);
        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    }

    private int getOrientation(int rotation) {
        return (ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation) + mSensorOrientation + 270) % 360;
    }

    private File getVideoFile(Context context) {
        return getOutputMediaFile();
    }

    private File getOutputMediaFile() {

        // External sdcard file location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(String.valueOf(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)));
//                new File(getE);
        // Create storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                // Log.d(TAG, "Oops! Failed create "+ VIDEO_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;

        //String vidFileName = Prefs.getString("docid", "null")+"_"+ timeStamp;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + Prefs.getString("docid", "null") + "_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        return mediaFile;
    }

    private void startRecordingVideo() {
        try {

            // UI
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    mButtonVideo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_stop);
                    mSaveVideo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

            mIsRecordingVideo = true;
            // Start recording
            if (flag == true){

                closePreviewSession();
                startPreview();
//                setUpMediaRecorder();
//                Log.d(TAG, "Media record stopped, setting up again");
//                if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
//                    openCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
//                } else {
//                    mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
//                }
//                startPreview();
//                setUpMediaRecorder();
            }
            mMediaRecorder.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception:: "+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void closePreviewSession() {
        if (mPreviewSession != null) {
            mPreviewSession.close();
            mPreviewSession = null;
        }
    }
    private void stopRecordingVideo() {
        // UI
        mIsRecordingVideo = false;
        mChronometer.stop();
        mButtonVideo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_record);
        mSaveVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        try {
            mMediaRecorder.stop();
            mMediaRecorder.reset();
            flag = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "media recorder released "+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    /**
     * Compares two {@code Size}s based on their areas.
     */
    static class CompareSizesByArea implements Comparator<Size> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
            // We cast here to ensure the multiplications won't overflow
            return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() -
                    (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
        }
    }
    public static class ErrorDialog extends DialogFragment {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Activity activity = getActivity();
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                    .setMessage("This device doesn't support Camera2 API.")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            activity.finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .create();
        }
    }
}
```

The camera preview and recording is done in a fragment. Can some one please check and help me here.

Thanks,
Arindam.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `MediaRecorder.setOrientationHint()` based on purely the display orientation of the device.

If you want it to be based also on how the device is oriented in the real world (so that down in the video is played back as down), you need to add more code to listen to orientation sensors of the device.

You can see code that should work for MediaRecorder as well in the reference docs of JPEG orientation in the camera API:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest?hl=en#JPEG_ORIENTATION

which uses [OrientationEventListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/OrientationEventListener?hl=en#onOrientationChanged(kotlin.Int))

```
private int getJpegOrientation(CameraCharacteristics c, int deviceOrientation) {
     if (deviceOrientation == android.view.OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return 0;
     int sensorOrientation = c.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);

     // Round device orientation to a multiple of 90
     deviceOrientation = (deviceOrientation + 45) / 90 * 90;

     // Reverse device orientation for front-facing cameras
     boolean facingFront = c.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT;
     if (facingFront) deviceOrientation = -deviceOrientation;

     // Calculate desired JPEG orientation relative to camera orientation to make
     // the image upright relative to the device orientation
     int jpegOrientation = (sensorOrientation + deviceOrientation + 360) % 360;

     return jpegOrientation;
 }
```

Comment: I have made the above things. Still it did not solve.

Comment: int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        // Choose the sizes for camera preview and video recording
        int orientation = getVideoOrientation(characteristics, rotation); // getResources().getConfiguration().orientation);
        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();

Answer (score 0):

I added the below code. Still it did not solve.

```
 private int getVideoOrientation(CameraCharacteristics c, int deviceOrientation) {
        if (deviceOrientation == android.view.OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return 0;
        int sensorOrientation = c.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);

        // Round device orientation to a multiple of 90
        deviceOrientation = (deviceOrientation + 45) / 90 * 90;

        // Reverse device orientation for front-facing cameras
        boolean facingFront = c.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT;
        if (facingFront) deviceOrientation = -deviceOrientation;


        // Calculate desired JPEG orientation relative to camera orientation to make
        // the image upright relative to the device orientation
        int videoOrientation = (sensorOrientation + deviceOrientation + 360) % 360;

        return videoOrientation;
    }


int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        // Choose the sizes for camera preview and video recording
        int orientation = getVideoOrientation(characteristics, rotation); // getResources().getConfiguration().orientation);
        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
```

Comment: Why the hell nobody knows that info?? Have u found a solution?